# How to iterate over a group of HTML elements with the same className and add a class based on Character Count and add a class using Dojo

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, dojo

I want to implement conditions where if I have a group of html elements with text that if they have `4` text characters I want to add a `class`. Here is my code which does not work:

```js
var attributeIcons = dojo.query(".attribute-icon");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(attributeIcons, function(el) {
  if (el.innerText.length === 4) {
    return domClass.add(attributeIcons, "new-class");
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By doesn't work do you mean that it doesn't add the classes to any elements or that it throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return just add a class using `classList.add`

```
var attributeIcons = dojo.query(".attribute-icon");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(attributeIcons, function(el) {
  if (el.innerText.trim().length === 4) {
    return el.classList.add("new-class");
  }
});
```

Comment: Even when I added the return keyword that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class to `el`:

```
return domClass.add(el, "new-class");
```

You could also change your code slightly more:

```
var attributeIcons = dojo.query(".attribute-icon");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(attributeIcons, function(el) {
  if (el.innerText.trim().length == 4) {
    return el.addClass("new-class");
  }
});
```